# What is the correct way to add new generated model file? in VS 2010 EF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am using the EF in VS2010. I first created a DB and then choose create model from DB.. Then I go and choose Add Code Generation item.. everything looks good so far.  Now I added a new table in my DB, I then choose update model from DB. This is still OK.  How do I tell VS 2010 to generate a model file for that new table?

I end up deleting everything and and repeating the step over and over for every time I make a change to the database. ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click on **Add Code Generation item** inside *.edmx it will create two files:

**YourModel.Context.tt** *(produces a strongly typed ObjectContext for the YourModel.edmx)*

**YourModel.tt** *(responsible for generating a file for each EntityType and ComplexType in the YourModel.Context.tt)*

When you update your *.edmx you just need to right click on YourModel.tt and choose **Run Custom Tool**.

More info:

Because you're using such approach i would recommend that you move the **YourModel.tt** file into the separate *Class Library* project (hold the *Shift* key and drag and move it)

Modify:

***string inputFile = @ "YourModel.edmx";*** to

***string inputFile = @ "..\YourNamespaceWhereEdmxIS\YourModel.edmx";***

in your **YourModel.tt**.

Change **Custom Tool Namespace** for your **YourModel.Context.tt** in the properties browser to match ***YourClassLibraryName***

Regards.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.  I think i've tried the run custom tool but it just flashes or does nothing.. I'll have to observe it closer.

Comment: was this additional step really necessary? i mean moving the file to a separate classlibrary?